# Getting exect time of currently playing flv video stream in flex videoPlayer?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video, mxml

How to get timestamp with milliseconds or better nanoseconds of currently playing video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NetStream.time` property is accurate to the millisecond.  The value is number of seconds, but it's `Number` and includes fractional seconds which the docs say are accurate to the millisecond.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#time

> This number is accurate to the thousandths decimal place; multiply by 1000 to get the number of milliseconds the stream has been playing.